# DevExpress WPF Grid - get number of rows

Tags: wpf, grid, devexpress

Does anyone knows how to get a DevExpress WPF Grid Rows count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure there is a way except by actually walking the visual tree (using VisualTreeHelper). How about something like (mygGidControl1.DataSource as ICollection).Count ?

Answer (score 9):

The number of rows displayed can change as users change the grouping, filterting.  Therefore, you should use the [GridControl.VisibleRowCount](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_VisibleRowCounttopic) property instead of the data source row count.